# A beginner — Why am I not able to convert to minutes?

Tags: python

```
minutes = input("Enter number of minutes you want to convert to seconds: ")
print (minutes + " minutes is " + float(minutes) * 60 + " seconds.")
```

I'm getting this error `can only concatenate str (not "float") to str`.
But if I use `str` (instead of `float`), it just prints the number of minutes inputted 10 times
eg `10101010....`

Comment: `float(minutes) * 60` is a number, you need to turn it into a string with `str()` to format it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `float(minutes) * 60` returns a float, which cannot be concatenated to a string. However, `str(minutes) * 60` will multiply the STRING minutes by 60, which is also not what you want.

The solution is to convert to float to perform the calculation, then convert back to a string. See the code below:

```py
minutes = input("Enter number of minutes you want to convert to seconds: ")
print (minutes + " minutes is " + str(float(minutes) * 60) + " seconds.")
```

If you input `3`, this code will print `3 minutes is 180.0 seconds.`

Other ways of doing the same thing include:

Format strings:

```py
print("%s is %0.1f seconds." % (minutes, float(minutes) * 60))
```

If you're using Python 3, f-strings:

```py
print(f"{minutes} is {float(minutes) * 60} seconds.")
```

Comment: You da bomb <3 ty

Comment: @OMGGItsRob No problem! I also edited in more methods to do this, so take a look. Also, if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

float(minutes) * 60 is not a string and therefore cannot be concatenated with with the rest of your string

consider converting float(minutes) * 60 to a string

```
minutes = input("Enter number of minutes you want to convert to seconds: ")
print (minutes + " minutes is " + str(float(minutes) * 60) + " seconds.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Although many answers have been added, but there is one more way other than those and as simple as all others, maybe even simpler. Just separate your different `data-types` with a `,`:)

```
print (minutes , "minutes is" , float(minutes) * 60 , "seconds.")
```

Comment: Note that the spaces aren't necessary because `print` will automatically put spaces between each item. This will format it a bit better: `print(minutes , "minutes is" , float(minutes) * 60 , "seconds.")`

Comment: Yeah that's true, I actually copied it from the question and just replaced the `+` signs. Although it won't make a difference as it's just a print statement:)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate string with a float Use a format string instead:

```
print("%s minutes is %f seconds" % (minutes, float(minutes) * 60))
10 minutes is 60.000000 seconds
```

Comment: This changes how to code is supposed to work. 10 minutes should be 600 seconds, not 10.

Comment: Yeah, left off the * 60 by mistake